# Trying to make sense of 私の国がオケを見たことについて悪い話をしないでください。そのすべての西洋私は私が嫌いな私は彼らが常に悪い国を与えるために嫌いを見つけるのが嫌い

Tags: translation, questions

I was watching a video about Hana Kimura's suicide. I was scrolling through the comments and I saw this comment:

> 私の国が**オケ**を見たことについて悪い話をしないでください。そのすべての西洋**私は私が嫌いな私は彼ら**が常に悪い国を与えるために嫌いを見つけるのが嫌い.

For reference, the two commentators were having an argument about one's validity of being Japanese and the nature of how toxic Japanese culture can be whilst in English, but one of them pulls out this unsightly sentence neither my mother nor I, can make tails of what it actually means.

My mother said this:

> "次は私も意味不明　
> オケって何？
> I hate myself for someone have been looking for bad reputation. And I knew it. That's why I hate myself.
> かな？"
> わかりません

Both of us are lost on what 'オケ' is even supposed to be. I'm even more lost on how they even got to this "私は私が嫌いな私は彼ら"

(Just to clarify, my mother is Japanese.)

Comment: We might know what it means if we can somehow determine what language this sentence was machine-translated from.

Comment: Just kind of shooting around but I think Ive got the first part. 

オケ being "okay," "Please dont say bad things about what, In my country, we have deemed okay." (perhaps like culturally accepted things that may seem odd to other countries, e.g. eating horses)

As for the second paragraph, yeah this seems to be quite bizzare of a sentence and perhaps it is machine translated but if I were to make a shot in the dark its something like

"Your just going around looking for bad things to say about western countries for the sake of finding bad things to say."

Comment: @UwU was the question written with the impression that this was a native Japanese speaker?

Comment: No, it was written with the idea 'wtf is this dude even trying to say with this broken Japanese?"

Comment: Okay... Just wondering what there is to be gleaned from a non-native's broken Japanese.